# XAML designer gives error - The name does not exist in namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp, namespaces, converters

What I am trying to do is to put a custom converter in my project using the Page.Resources in XAML.

I am stuck doing this since visual studio is throwing an error that says

> 'The name 'DoubleValueConverter' does not exist in the namespace'

This is the error that it is throwing
[image: This is the error that it is throwing]

This is the code from my custom converter
[image: This is the code from my custom converter]

Comment: Please read [ask]. Also, notice that your code has compilation errors

Comment: Checked if you are missing an import (`using`)? If yes the compiler cannot find the Interface (the .cs file). Does it even exist?

Comment: Please don't post code as image, but as text. It's easier to read and to search. And I guess you have to use the fullqualified name of the converter: `MAD_Les8_Binding.Converters1.DoubleValueConverter` in the xaml

Comment: Images of code are absolutely useless here. See [this Meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/62576) for a list of the many reasons they should not be used. Code is text, and can be copied and pasted directly into your post and properly formatted. Please do so. Thanks. (When you created your account here, it was suggested you take the [tour] and read the [help] pages. Please do that as well, especially [ask] and [mcve], before asking your next question here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The signature of the methods is incorrect, you have provided the signature of WPF `IValueConverter`, the signature of Convert in UWP is

```
Convert(Object, Type, Object, String)
(last Argument is of `String` and not `CultureInfo`)
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter

Because of this you cannot build your project, and there for the designer complains about not finding the converter.

Additionally, as René Voigt mentioned in the comments you didnt provide the fullyqualified Name and only point to the parent class (which isnt declared public, not sure if that makes a problem) - I would recommend removing the nesting - so remove the class around the two converter - `DoubleValueConverter`.

Answer (score 1):

Well,pretty much impossible to say for sure because your first image is too small to see clearly when zooming in,but isnt the error telling you that the namespace you are trying to use is called

> "usingMad_Les8_Binding.Converter1"

instead of what i suppose what was intended to be

> "Mad_Les8_Binding.Converter1"

?

Edit:as others said above,dont post images but code,otherwise this happens

Comment: The using: syntax is to actually include the namespace so you can utilize what's defined within it.  Unless it is missing the ":", this shouldn't cause any problem.

Comment: @AndréB "Using" is fine,but if he wrote it without a space or other separator as it seems to be (as i said,images are an awful idea) i really dont think it can be right.At that point,he's just calling a different namespace.If the separator is there yhen yes,that's not the problem.